# ¿Cómo puedo retornar una cadena modificada de una funcion void?

Tags: string, funciones, estructuras, prototipos

**Se me pide que realice lo siguiente:**

Definir la clase usando 'struct' en lugar de 'class', ya que todos los elementos de la clase deben ser accesibles desde la interfaz.

Debe almacenar en una variable miembro de la clase un número entero (unsigned int num;). El número debe ser sin signo (solo acepta números positivos) para facilitar las cosas.Debe tener las siguientes funciones miembro (usar los mismos prototipos):

```
void dec( char* string );   // modifica string para almacenar una cadena que representa el número en decimal

void bin( char* string );   // modifica string para almacenar una cadena que representa el número en binario

void oct( char* string );   // modifica string para almacenar una cadena que representa el número en octal

void hex( char* string );   // modifica string para almacenar una cadena que representa el número en hexadecimal
```

Las funciones reciben como parámetro una cadena de tipo C que debe ser definida fuera de la clase. Para esto no se requiere usar memoria dinámica, usen una cadena normal de C. Las funciones regresan su resultado en esta cadena, modificando su contenido (hay que declarar espacio suficiente).
Las funciones realizan la conversión del numero almacenado en la variable num a una cadena con la representación del número en:

**decimal**

**binario**

**octal**

**hexadecimal**

**Ya tengo definido en mi archivo.hh**

```
#ifndef INTBASE_HPP    
#define INTBASE_HPP

struct int_base{

void dec( char* string );

void bin( char* string );

void oct( char* string );

void hex( char* string );

unsigned int num;

}

string cadena;

#endif // INTBASE_HPP
    
**y en mi archivo int_base.cpp:**

#include"intbase.hpp"
    
void dec( char* cadena ){

}

void bin( char* cadena ){

}

void oct( char* cadena ){

}

void hex( char* cadena ){

}
```

No tengo idea de como hacerle ya que las funciones reciben cadenas y las modifican pero no retornan nada ya que son void? que tengo que hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Ciertamente puedes modificar la cadena de carácteres desde la función, pero no la puedes regresar porque es **void**, no hay forma de hacerlo sin cambiar el prototipo (cosa que no te dejan hacer), por lo que a la única conclusión a la que puedo llegar es que cuando en el enunciado se habla de "regresar", no se refiere al hecho de que la función devuelva un valor con **return**, sino que la cadena *"entrará"* sin datos escritos previamente y *"saldrá"* con algo escrito, es decir los números en las bases indicadas; creo que lo que sucede aquí es un error en la forma en la que se escribió el enunciado, de manera que no te preocupes por que en él diga "regresar", no tienes que hacer nada especial, solo programa tus funciones como se te indica y ya porque aquí regresar es igual a salir (cuando la función termine) no a devolver.

Comment: gracias, entonces solo hago el cambio de base

Comment: De nada si, solo haz el cambio de base.

Comment: Para ello primero necesito una cadena de caracteres, luego lo convierto a numero, luego hago las operaciones y luego lo regreso a la misma cadena de caracteres y ya en el main.cpp que lo imprima, pero... cómo hago para que me tome la cadena de caracteres ? me confunde el parametro char* string

Comment: Ejm: char input[64]; dec(input); desde la función escribes los datos como si el puntero a carácter fuera un array; y listo.

Comment: Imaginemos que tengo los calculos para convertir de Decimal a Binario  que están en este código:

Comment: int main()
{
    int decimal;
    short binario[8];

    cout << "Teclea el valor en decimal a convertir:" << endl;
    cin >> decimal;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        binario[i] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
    }

    cout << "El numero en binario es:" << endl;

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << binario[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    
}

Comment: ¿Cómo lo implemento en la funcion para que en el main.cpp salga una cadena? Lo siento pero sufro mucho con punteros y cadenas

Comment: Te voy a dar la implementación de una función para que te guíes, pero el resto las haces tu, void dec(char* in){ unsigned copy = num; /*este es el num del enunciado*/ unsigned i; for(i = 1u; (copy /= 10u) != 0u; ++i); copy = num; do{in[i] = ((char)(copy % 10u)) + '0'; copy /= 10u;}while((--i) != 0u);} /*y básicamente es el mismo proceso con el resto de funciones*/

Answer (score 1):

Con lo que estás teniendo dudas es con como pasa los valores el Lenguaje C y C++: en estos, los parámetros se pasan por referencia, ¿qué quiere decir esto? que se copian los parámetros que le pasas a la función en los que luego realmente se ejecutan en esta, no alterando así el valor inicial de estos.

Desconozco si sabes acerca de punteros, pero básicamente, al pasa `char*` lo que estás pasando es un puntero, que es un valor que apunta a una zona de memoria como su nombre indica, por tanto ahí sí estás modificando el valor normal (no sé si has trabajado con vectores, pero estos son esto mismo: punteros).

Por tanto podrías trabajar sobre el elemento original así:

```
char elemementooriginal[]="Este es el elemento original";
oct(elementooriginal);
```

Es algo complejo como C trabaja con los parámetros en funciones, punteros, etc.

Comment: de hecho si tengo una duda, ya que mi parametro de entrada es char* string para las funciones... cómo se supone que voy a crear las cadenas para que las reciba? entiendo que el char* es un puntero pero no me queda claro como voy a ingresar el parametro (osea como voy a ingresar el numero dentro de una cadena)